# Is there a case where '&' yields a lower performance than '%'?

Tags: c, performance, modulo, bitwise-and

The following two code sequences produce the same result:

```
uint mod = val % 4;

uint mod1 = val & 0x3;
```

I can use both to calculate the same result. I know that in hardware the `&` operator is much more simpler realised than the `%` operator. Therefore I expect it to have a better performance than the `%` operator.

Can I always assume that the `&` has a better or equal performance?
Does a compiler optimize this automatically?

Comment: You can never assume anything about what or how the compiler optimizes. The standard explicitly leaves this up to the compiler. And in case you don't just need the remainder but the quotient as well, [check out div()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div).

Comment: any reasonably modern compiler will **far** outperform any human in these kinds of micro-optimizations. always use the the construct that most clearly represent intent.

Comment: No, you cannot really assume the compiler will always optimize the code. However, yes, `&` is typically faster. What you write should be what you really intend.

Comment: @sp2danny you clearly haven't seen Chandler Carruth showing how his custom modulo function surprisingly, also too him, outperformed `%` at https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk :-) (that said - I agree that the readable and non-surprising version should be used until proven otherwise in perf measurements)

Comment: For readability, maintainability and to be sure there is no misunderstood behavior, never, never, never use trick. You want a modulo ? do a modulo! You want a bit masking ? do a bit masking, but don't do a bit masking to have a modulo!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't assume anything about either of these operations, a compile *could* optimise both to the same instructions.

And, indeed, both `clang` and `gcc` will translate them into a single `and` instruction.

Unfortunately, due to the nature of `%` having a specified return value for negative values since ISO C99, some extra work is required for `signed` integers. As opposed to ISO C90, where negative modulo was implementation defined.

The resulting assembly for both operations, on either `signed` and `unsigned` values:

**`modulo` with signed integers:**

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]       ; grab `val`
cdq                                  ; convert 32-bit EAX to 64-bit
                                     ; and fill EDX with the sign bit
shr     edx, 30                      ; shift EDX by 30 positions to the right
                                     ; leaving only the two left-most bits
add     eax, edx                     ; add EDX to EAX
and     eax, 3                       ; do the AND
sub     eax, edx                     ; subtract EDX from EAX
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+8], eax       ; move result on stack
```

This is neat trick, to have properly defined behaviour for negative values. It's doing `((val + 3) & 3) - 3` for negative values, and `val & 3` for positive.

**`and` with signed/unsigned and `modulo` with unsigned:**

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
and     eax, 3
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+12], eax
```

Comment: The reason for the different assembly output between & and % is that they do not return the same result. `(-1 & 0x03) = 3` while `(-1 % 3) = -1`

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis Absolutely correct, fixed it, and also added an explanation of the different behaviours for `signed` and `unsigned` integers.

Comment: @ElderBug I've added an explanation to point out the difference between a `signed` and `unsigned` operation.

Comment: As a complement, I would add that the `cdq + shr` is actually a nice trick to handle the negative part. `cdq` will fill `edx` with the sign bit of `eax`. Combined with the shift, the whole thing will do `((val+3)&3)-3` for negative values, and only `val&3` for positive values.

Comment: @ElderBug Sweet! I was trying to figure out where the value of `edx` was coming from.  That's a neat trick!

Answer (score 1):

A (modern) compiler should generate the same code from your example, and the reason of this optimization is that the rhs is a compile constant.

As far as I know, the `&` operator is done with one processor instruction `and`; it's not the case with the modulo operator which generally implies far more operations (computing the remainder of the integer division). AFAIK, it is generally longer than a multiplication; I consider it as long as an integer division.